# Shooting location for Cloud Atlas: where is this tower?

Tags: film-location, cloud-atlas

I would love to find out the name of this tower:

[image: tower]

It's in Cambridge, but that's about all I know. It's for a project. IMDB is pretty inconsequential.

Is there a better website for finding film locations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah just found it.

[It's called Scott Monument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Monument)

It's not actually in Cambridge! That's what was throwing me.

Comment: Since you answered your own question, you please mark it as "answered" so as to close the loop. It is proper and helps keep the site cleaned up!

Comment: And, how did you find it?

Comment: Really random goggling. I don't think it would help anyone, it wasn't a system anyone could use to find another location!

Comment: It's actually stated in the movie that it's the Scott Monument, and that the character is in Edinburgh at the time (travelling from Cambridge to be the composer's understudy).

Comment: Yeah I found out it wasn't Cambridge after, but this film was complicated enough already!